# kableExtra::kable table wont display when being called by markdown::render()

Tags: r, r-markdown

When I knit the following .rmd file, I get a table (even though its ugly) in the PDF that is generated.

````
---
output: pdf_document
params:
  test: 1
---

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
kable(iris[params$test])
```
````

output:
[screenshot of pdf table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qiQJ.png)

But when I call the above .rmd file from the below .r file using markdown::render(), The table looses its format.

```
#setwd("~/CRD/SAMS/testing_render_problem")

library(rmarkdown)

rmarkdown::render(input = "test_sams.rmd",
                  params = list(
                    test = 1))
```

output:
[screenshot of pdf without table formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNrkD.png)

**Any ideas of how I can get tables to display in PDFs generated by using the render() function?**

For context I am automating some report generation, so I need to use render() (unless there's a better alternative..) so I can produce 400+ reports by clicking one button.

Here is my sessionInfo()

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] stringi_1.7.5    gtable_0.3.0     magrittr_2.0.1   anchors_3.0-8    MASS_7.3-54      rgenoud_5.8-3.0  reshape2_1.4.4  
 [8] kableExtra_1.3.4 knitr_1.36       forcats_0.5.1    stringr_1.4.0    dplyr_1.0.7      purrr_0.3.4      tidyr_1.1.4     
[15] tibble_3.1.5     ggplot2_3.3.5    tidyverse_1.3.1  readr_2.0.2      gridExtra_2.3    rmarkdown_2.11  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7        svglite_2.0.0     lubridate_1.8.0   assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.28     utf8_1.2.2        R6_2.5.1         
 [8] cellranger_1.1.0  plyr_1.8.6        backports_1.3.0   reprex_2.0.1      evaluate_0.14     highr_0.9         httr_1.4.2       
[15] pillar_1.6.4      rlang_0.4.12      readxl_1.3.1      rstudioapi_0.13   labeling_0.4.2    webshot_0.5.2     tinytex_0.34     
[22] bit_4.0.4         munsell_0.5.0     broom_0.7.10      compiler_4.1.0    modelr_0.1.8      xfun_0.27         pkgconfig_2.0.3  
[29] systemfonts_1.0.3 htmltools_0.5.2   tidyselect_1.1.1  fansi_0.5.0       viridisLite_0.4.0 crayon_1.4.2      tzdb_0.2.0       
[36] dbplyr_2.1.1      withr_2.4.2       jsonlite_1.7.2    lifecycle_1.0.1   DBI_1.1.1         scales_1.1.1      vroom_1.5.5      
[43] cli_3.1.0         farver_2.1.0      fs_1.5.0          xml2_1.3.2        ellipsis_0.3.2    generics_0.1.1    vctrs_0.3.8      
[50] tools_4.1.0       bit64_4.0.5       glue_1.4.2        hms_1.1.1         parallel_4.1.0    fastmap_1.1.0     yaml_2.2.1       
[57] colorspace_2.0-2  rvest_1.0.2       haven_2.4.3
```

Thanks in advance!

Joshua

Comment: I haven't this problem. A table has borders. We need more info about your working conditions.

Comment: @manro, Thanks for taking a look at this! What info would be helpful?

Comment: Your Rstudio, your R version etc

Comment: Strange behaviour, it should work...

Answer (score 0):

I still dont know why kable doesnt work, but if anyone else encounters this problem, library(gridExtra) works for me.

```
#kable(iris[params$test])
grid.table(iris[params$test])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).